# Install UWP package on Windows 8.1 Pro without developers license

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-8.1

With Xamarin.Forms I'm developing a mobile app. In Android I get this succesfully running on a device. I succeeded to create an app package from the UWP project and install it on my own Windows 10 PC. This is also my developing machine, so it's in Developer Mode by default. So it runs here without any problems.

My purpose is to get it running on Windows 8.1 Pro (tablet size). It just needs to consume the app. When installing the app by using the script, it's throwing the error that no developers license is found. On this device I didn't found anything to put it in Developers Mode, but it seems me that this is not needed, because it only consuming the app and no developing will take place on it.

It's is an internal app, so no need to place it on the Windows Store.

So my exact question: how can I install this app on this device without setting everything up for a Developer?

Comment: Windows 8.1 can't run UWP apps in the first place - UWP is new to Windows 10. Even if you manage to set up your Windows 8.1 machine with the right permissions, it's not going to be able to run your app.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the answer! So none of the Windows 8 device (PC's or phones) would run a UWP app, this can be used starting from the Windows 10 devices.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be no. Windows 10 has more new API and concepts that are not available on Windows 8.1. UWP app will not backward compatible to Windows 8.1. But WRT app will be Upward compatible to windows 10. It means that the windows 8 store app could run in windows 10. for more please refer [**Move from Windows Runtime 8.x to UWP**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-root).